# Error starting the fish_config web ui in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fish

I want to customize my `fish` shell using the Web UI mode, but when running `fish_config colors`, the following error is shown.

```
surface@Surface ~> fish_config starting-colors
Web config started at file:///tmp/web_configoafehdco.html
Hit ENTER to stop.
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "file:///tmp/web_configoafehdco.html"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommandd
```

I am running Ubuntu in the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After going through some articles and not finding the correct answer, I found that when running `'help'`
it opens the browser and points to

```
file://wsl%24/Ubuntu-20.04/usr/share/doc/fish/index.html#variables-for-changing-highlighting-colors
```

and when we're trying to run **fish_config**, it points to

```
"file://wsl%24/Ubuntu/tmp/web_configpo_b9wan.html"
```

That means, we need to change our wsl%24/Ubuntu to wsl%24/Ubuntu-20.04.

To do so, first of all, open the webconfig directory.

```
cd /usr/share/fish/tools/web_config
```

Now, give write permission to the webconfig.py file.

```
sudo chmod 777 webconfig.py
```

Modify the following line from `"file:///" + f.name"` to `"file://wsl%24/Ubuntu-20.04" + f.name` in webconfig.py file.

---

Change the file's permission back to its original state by running `chmod 644 webconfig.py`

You're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this problem is happening because your WSL2 distro might not have the latest version of `fish`.
The solution would be to fix the `wsl` detection for `fish` in `/usr/share/fish/tools/web_config/webconfig.py`.

Edit your `/usr/share/fish/tools/web_config/webconfig.py` and change the `is_wsl()` function to be the same as this:

```py
 def is_wsl(): 
     """ Return whether we are running under the Windows Subsystem for Linux """ 
     if "linux" in platform.system().lower() and os.access("/proc/version", os.R_OK): 
         with open("/proc/version", "r") as f: 
             # Find 'Microsoft' for wsl1 and 'microsoft' for wsl2 
             if "microsoft" in f.read().lower(): 
                 return True 
     return False
```

In particular, **change "Microsoft" to "microsoft"** *(Uppercase to lowercase "m")*

For more info, read [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4299#issuecomment-695216128) opened at the fish shell's github repo.